# I have a matrix with two column, How can I make correlation every 21 rows?

Tags: matlab

I want to put these in a loop:

```
r1 = corr(a(1:21,1),a(1:21,2),'type','Pearson');
r2 = corr(a(22:42,1),a(22:42,2),'type','Pearson');
r3 = corr(a(43:63,1),a(43:63,2),'type','Pearson');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
% Pre-allocate according to the size of the output
for k=1:3
   r(:,:,k) = corr(a(21*k-20:21*k,1),a(21*k-20:21*k,2),'type','Pearson');
end
```

Comment: Mr. Sardar, Can I ask one more favor, how to put all of them in 1 vector? Many thanks.

Comment: @rafat Why? A vector only has one non-singleton dimension, so you'd be losing pretty much all of the description from your descriptive statistics...

Comment: Dear excaza, I am now try to find the quality of the reg, we are not sure about these data, in case we got high R^2 then we can extend to the next step, or we should look for another time series, after Sardar's help, I start to see R^2 are higher than 0.9 wish is pretty good.